# How to get a character from its ASCII value?

Tags: swift

I want to get letters from their ASCII code in Swift 3. I would do it like this in Java :

```
for(int i = 65 ; i < 75 ; i++)
{
    System.out.print((char)i);
}
```

Which would log letters from A to J.

Now I tried this in Swift :

```
let s = String(describing: UnicodeScalar(i))
```

Instead of only getting the letter, I get this :

```
Optional("A")
Optional("B")
Optional("C")
...
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`UnicodeScalar`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unicodescalar) has a few failable initialisers for integer types that can reprent values that aren't valid Unicode code points. Therefore you'll need to unwrap the `UnicodeScalar?` returned, as in the case that you pass an invalid code point, the initialiser will return `nil`.

However, given that you're dealing exclusively with ASCII characters, you can simply annotate `i` as a `UInt8` and take advantage of the fact that `UnicodeScalar` has a [non-failable initialiser for a `UInt8` input](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unicodescalar/1538446-init) (as it will always represent a valid code point):

```
for i : UInt8 in 65..<75 {
    print(UnicodeScalar(i))
}
```